# Benefits for women in Ontario

Tags: canada, unemployment

Im unemployed i apply for a jobs but not luckly call for an interview yet. I will be separating soon with my husband . I lived in Eastern Ontario near Renfrew. Not much jobs around here i wanted to-move in toronto. Can i apply a ontario works there in toronto instead here in Eastern Ontario? Plus i dont have a home because my would be ex husband terminate the house we are renting , what would be my option right now .?

Answer (score 2):

I don't live in Canada and am unfamiliar with how things work over there but it looks from the [Toronto Ontario Works page](https://www.toronto.ca/community-people/employment-social-support/support-for-people-in-financial-need/assistance-through-ontario-works/) (under the Who Can Apply tab) that you need to be a Toronto resident to apply for Ontario Works there.

I could be wrong though, your best bet would be to contact both your local Ontario Works office and the Toronto one. Here is the contact page for the various offices:

https://www.mcss.gov.on.ca/en/mcss/programs/social/ow/contacts/ow_contacts.aspx

Here is the general information page for Ontario Works (there's a link to the online application form if you prefer that):

https://www.mcss.gov.on.ca/en/mcss/programs/social/ow/

And Ontario's Affordable Housing page:

https://www.ontario.ca/page/affordable-housing-ontario

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You might also qualify for Employment Insurance if you have recently become unemployed. To understand if you qualify you should read the eligibility criteria [here](https://www.canada.ca/en/services/benefits/ei/ei-regular-benefit/eligibility.html). If you need help filling out your application, or have any questions you can call Service Canada at 1-800-206-7218 or search "Settlement Services" on the [Services Near Me](https://settlement.org/findhelp/ontario/) website.

Also, check out the [Employment Ontario (ontrac) website](http://www.employmentnetworks.ca). Which has employment services for Renfrew and the surrounding area including training programs, and job openings.